# Datatables - Return Column as HTML <td> Element

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

I'm having some difficulty migrating some Client Side Datatables logic to Server Side.

My current issue is that with Datatables, if you want to paginate a large set of data (20,000+ rows) I first need to load all the rows in the Controller and then pass them to the view:

```
$records = \App\Records::get();

return view("example.datatables")->with(["records" => $records]);
```

Following that, this takes about 2 minutes of waiting before everything is loaded and Datatables paginates the records into pages of 500:

```
$("#table").DataTable({
  paging: true,
  pageLength: 500,
  ...
});
```

I've changed the Datatables declaration to handle Server Side processing via `ajax` like so:

```
$("#table").DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: {
    url: "...",
    type: "GET"
  }, paging: true,
  pageLength: 500,
  ...
});
```

Getting this to work as I'd like has gone quite well, but the issue is that Datatables is overriding or ignoring what I'm sending back from my `ajax` request:

```
$columnData = [];
foreach($recordsFromDatabase AS $record){
  $columnDataObject = [];

  $columnDataObject[0] = '<td class="myClass" data-property="myProperty"><input type="text" name="customInput[]"/></td>'

  ...

  $columnData[] = $columnDataObject;
}

return response()->json([
  "draw" => (int)$request->input("draw"),
  "recordsTotal" => $totalRecords,
  "recordsFiltered" => $totalFilteredRecords,
  "data" => $columnData,
  "error" => null
]);
```

Basically, what I'm sending back is a `json` response containing `data`, which is an array of columns, which are `<td>` elements, instead of just a plain value. So `<td>Value</td>` vs `Value`.

Datatables gives the illusion that this is working correctly, but I end up with

```
<tr role="row" class="even">
  <td class="sorting_1"><input type="text" name="customInput[]"/></td>
  ...
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd">
  <td class="sorting_1"><input type="text" name="customInput[]"/></td>
  ...
</tr>
```

It renders the `<input>` inside of the `<td>` correctly, but `class="myClass" data-property="myProperty"` are missing, which destroys the extended functionality of my table.

Is there some way to tell Datatables that what I'm sending back are valid `<td>` elements, and all it needs to do is add an `odd` or `even` class? (and even then, that's just for styling I think).

Comment: Look up laravel pagination https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination

Comment: This is not an issue with Laravel pagination, nor pagination in general really.

Comment: You do not need Datatables when you can do all of this with laravels pagination classes and doing it with pagination will sped up the process in general because youll be processing chunks of x instead of 20,000

Comment: I know that, and believe me, I don't want to use Datatables for that very reason alone, but I am locked in due to client requirements. Also, it's a pretty niche issue, so even though Laravel Pagination would work wonders, it's not an option for me. Cheers on the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up still sending HTML via my response, and using datatable's `createdRow` callback, I was able to parse the HTML into local DOM elements, check their classes and attributes, and assign them to the row/column as required:

```
createdRow: function(row, data, rowIndex) {
  $.each($("td", row), function (colIndex) {
    var elementFromData = $.parseHTML(data[colIndex]);
    var element = elementFromData[0];

    var elementClass = $(element).attr("class");
    if(typeof elementClass !== undefined){
      $(this).addClass(elementClass);
    }

    var attributes = [
      {
        label: "data-id",
        value: $(element).attr("data-id")
      }, ...
    ];

    for(var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++){
      var attribute = attributes[i];

      if(typeof attribute.value !== undefined){
        $(this).attr(attribute.label, attribute.value);
      }
    }
  });
}, ...
```

It may not be the prettiest solution, and I understand that returning HTML from my AJAX request is inefficient, but due to time constraints this was the best solution I could come up with.

Answer (score 3):

You're using jQuery DataTables incorrectly.

You should not send `<td>` elements as your data. Use [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option to produce content for your cell and/or [`columns.createdCell`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) option to add attributed to `<td>` element.

For example:

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 3,
    "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
      $(td)
        .attr('data-property', rowData['myCustomProperty'])
        .addClass(rowData['myClass']);
    }
  } ]
} );
```

For Laravel use excellent [Laravel DataTables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) package to correctly display table in server-side processing mode.

Comment: I figured I was using it wrong by sending `html` back, thanks for clearing that up. Only issue is these `data-*` attributes I need to send back have to be generated Server Side; what would be return data look like to handle that?

Comment: For example, on the first `<td>`, I need `data-record-id="'.$record->id.'">...</td>`, so it either needs to be a property on the Server Side, or somehow passed to JS via the `response`

Comment: @TimLewis, you can send IDs as part of your response. You don't have to assign `data-` attributes just to retrieve ID, full row data is available at any time using [`row().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()) API method and you can pass `tr` element as an argument to `row()` function.